# Redirecting all API routes using nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm in the process of switching from Apache to Nginx and have the following code in my Apache VirtualHost:

```
RedirectMatch 307 ^/api/v1(/.*|$) http://legacy.website.com/api/v1$1
```

I would like to redirect API calls to our old client for the time being. Would this be an acceptable way of accomplishing this using Nginx?

```
location /api/v1 {
    return 307 http://legacy.website.com/api/v1$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not capture a value for `$1`. You could change the `location` block from a prefix type to a regular expression type, but note that its evaluation order will also change. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1(/.*|$) {
    return 307 http://legacy.website.com/api/v1$1;
}
```